# Is using $.get to manipulate data a bad idea?

Tags: jquery, razor

In the Steven Sanderson book, it's said that using get to delete, update,... he recomand ti use Post. Is not a good idea. Let's say I have a link that says "disable" to disable a record. I'd like to use

```
$.get(...)
```

Instead of

```
@html.ActionLink("Disable",
```

To disable that row. is it still bad to use getajax function?

## EDIT

```
<a id = "disable_@Model.ID" class = "disable" href = "#">Disable</a>
```

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, the main problem with this method is that browsers tend to assume "getting" something to be a pretty harmless action. And not just browsers - even web crawlers from search engines, looking around at each available link, might go to that URL to see what might be there.

Plus, it means that all the details of every request is very easy to snoop on - even an HTTPS-encrypted transmission could show the URL requested as "`updatePatientDetails.php?diagnosisTitle=Anal_Inflammation&patientSSN=100101011`"

Yeah, this is not one of those "light" recommendations that everyone just ignores anyway. At the very least, I'd rather someone improperly use POST requests for everything - but not GET.

Comment: I understand what you both of you said. Now look at the edit. The destination is not there. The javascript is the one to to the get ajax. Still unsafe?

Comment: I don't think that edit changes anything. A) Webcrawlers either already do, or probably will, look inside of JavaScript for links. B) The security concern is still present, and there are even a number of other hard-to-perceive ways that browsers use these. A search plugin could do a GET to show you a screenshot of a page. Browsing plugins preload pages with GET requests. Going Back/Forward to a page uses a simple GET requests. ALL of that risk is negated if you use proper actions like POST or DELETE.

Answer (score 3):

Once someone made Delete Database links (as an a href) which posted GET requests to the server, then a search engine came along and found this "hidden admin page" and clicked each link.

GET requests are a developer's way to label something "safe" for search engines, browser pre-caching, etc. Never use them for data-changing functionality.